# Help with Geometric or Arithmetic progression

Tags: sequences-and-series, arithmetic

Evaluate
$$2004\cdot\left(\frac{1}{1\cdot2} + \frac{1}{2\cdot3} + \frac{1}{3\cdot4}+\dots + \frac{1}{2003\cdot2004}\right)$$
I think that this is based on either geometric or arithmetic progressions but I am not sure.
Please help me solve this problem.

Comment: Does $1/(2 \times 3) = 1/2 - 1/3$?  Does this keep working all the way down your sum?

Comment: yup, up till 2003*2004

Comment: Write the first few terms.  Anything cancel?

Comment: nope these are the simplified ones( the sum)

Comment: So, $1/2-1/3+1/3-1/4+1/4-1/5+ \cdots$ doesn't have any evident cancellation?

Comment: This is a [telescoping series](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Telescoping_series).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should know that $\dfrac{1}{x(x+1)}=\dfrac{1}{x}-\dfrac{1}{x+1}$.

Apply this to your series. I will ignore the $2004$ factor for now.
$$\frac{1}{1\cdot 2}+\frac{1}{2\cdot 3}+\dots+\frac{1}{2003\cdot 2004}=1\color{red}{\underbrace{-\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{2}}}\color{#AB4DEF}{\underbrace{-\frac{1}{3}+\frac{1}{3}}}\dots\color{orange}{\underbrace{-\frac{1}{2003}+\frac{1}{2003}}}-\frac{1}{2004}$$
See how you can cancel pretty much all the terms? What you are left with is $1-\dfrac{1}{2004}$, which equals $\dfrac{2003}{2004}$. Now don't forget that $2004$ factor at the left.
$$\color{blue}{2004}\cdot\frac{2003}{\color{blue}{2004}}=2003$$
$$\displaystyle \color{green}{\boxed{\therefore 2004\cdot\left(\dfrac{1}{1\cdot 2}+\dfrac{1}{2\cdot 3}+\dfrac{1}{3\cdot 4}+\dots + \dfrac{1}{2003\cdot 2004}\right)=2003}}$$

---

If you want to see why $\dfrac{1}{x(x+1)}=\dfrac{1}{x}-\dfrac{1}{x+1}$, it is easy to prove. Just use LHS-RHS. I will try to make $\dfrac{1}{x}-\dfrac{1}{x+1}$ equal to $\dfrac{1}{x(x+1)}$.
$$\frac{1}{x}-\dfrac{1}{x+1}=\frac{x+1}{x(x+1)}-\frac{x}{x(x+1)}=\frac{x+1-x}{x(x+1)}=\frac{1}{x(x+1)}$$
$$\therefore \frac{1}{x}-\frac{1}{x+1}=\frac{1}{x(x+1)} \ \ \text{by LHS-RHS}$$

Comment: Formally this is called http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Telescoping_series